# Typescript behaviour while spreading object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have function that accept:

- object that should be modified
- keys of this object that should be modified

And for selected keys, value of object's field should become equal to false.

```js
const modifiedObj = modifyObjectKeys({ object: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, keys: ['b'] });

modifiedObj // {a: 1, b: false, c: 3}
```

I created a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAeQEYCsIGNgAaKAaQhHiggA9gIA7AEyoEEAndgQxDQGsKAewBmUbHkIA+SVAC8UAN5QA2uRBQAlgygCQIsbgLAAugC4yFanUYsLlZQ0QBbLBHbGoAfigAGKOfEjVQoPAF8AbgAoSPxBBnhgKCdBJg1hEEDCNSp5TENCK3pmKjhY9iY0BPYtAHMSRAY+BkEAdwZJEmzCmzZOHn4hUUzgaQAKBUioKEF84kmdCngiSNDzJRmJYADZkl14cy7QgEpzOCRUPM3OxZlZGQmp2PjE9gQURPklADofjaMoCLzPZfYSCdgAUS4+AAFqNRrojnJ7vMpq9zsBlLoPPIfFEpsdoqiIMBEOxtGj3lFQtEngkkik0hoIExxHJ6al0sNsuNprM1lAuOYAIwkLDmABMJHw5gAzADdotzMoAORYZVhI5RZIcpks3BfLByWQ4qAAelNUGA7EQECAA) with my solution.

```js
type Result<Object, Keys extends Array<keyof Object>> = { [Key in keyof Object]: Key extends Keys[number] ? false : Object[Key] };

const modifyObjectKeys = <Object extends Record<string, unknown>, Keys extends Array<keyof Object>>({
  object,
  keys,
}: { object: Object, keys: Keys }): Result<Object, Keys> => {
  const result = { ...object };
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    result[key] = false; // here is an error as result[key] should be 1, 2, or 3 but not false
  })

  return result;
}

const modifiedObj = modifyObjectKeys({ object: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, keys: ['b'] });
modifiedObj.b === false // true
```

But here is some problem. When spreading `const result = { ...object };`, const result gets "Object" type and later I get error that "boolean" value is not assignable to it.

The only option I see is to use "as" operator like this:
`const result = { ...object } as Result<Object, Keys>;`

Are there any more precise approaches?

Comment: I would suggest not to shadow the builtin `Object` with a type parameter. Rename it to something else.

Comment: You probably want to use `{ [Key in keyof Object]: false | Object[Key] }` instead, or at least as an intermediate type. Notice also that calling `modifyObjectKeys<{'a': true}, 'a'[]>({a: true}, [])` (with an empty array, while declaring that the array may contain `'a'`s) is legitimate and returns `{a: true}` not `{a: false}` as your `Result` type would suggest.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for help, I updated my example changed Object to Data and also change Object[Key] to false | Object[Key] as you suggested. But still I have error while returning final object. Can you please check this one: https://playcode.io/1293082

Comment: Yes, you would need to use a type assertion (`as`) to tell TypeScript that none of the keys mentioned in the type parameter have a value of type `Object[Key]` any longer. (And as mentioned, this would not actually be factually correct, which is why the assertion is necessary, but it's probably still "useful").